# Carbon in Laravel 4 InvalidArgumentException - Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm trying to get an Eloquent query result for `DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%m-%d-%Y %r') AS created_at")` but each time I get this exception from Carbon:

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unexpected data found. Trailing data
```

If I change it to just `created_at` instead of employing MySQL's `DATE_FORMAT()` function, then it gets the data without issue.

I've not only done this sort of date formatting without issue before, but I checked every field in the database table (there are only 10 for this seed) and each is a standard valid date, so I'm wondering why Carbon is pitching a fit.

Running this in Laravel 4.1.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In an `Eloquent` query result (model) every `date` field is a [carbon object](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), it means, if you query a model which contains any `timestamp` field like `created_at`, `updated_at`  (basically created using `timestamps()` during migration) and `deleted_at`, `Laravel` converts them to a `Carbon` object and you may use any public methods of `Carbon`, for example:

```
$user = User::find(1);

// '2014-04-20 19:02:09' will become 'Apr 20, 2014'
$user->created_at->toFormattedDateString();
```

So, you may directly use any public method of `Carbon` on a `timestamp` field available in a model. If you try this:

```
dd($user->created_at);
```

Then the output will be:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)[456]
  public 'date' => string '2014-04-20 19:02:09' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

So, if you want to `format` a date, you may use:

```
// outputs like: 'Sunday 20th of April 2014 07:02:09 PM'
$user->created_at->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')
```

### Update:

If you want to change this behavior, means that, if you want tell `Laravel` that, which fields should be converted automatically to `Carbon` object then you may override that by creating a method in your model like:

```
public function getDates()
{
    // only this field will be converted to Carbon
    return array('updated_at');
}
```

To totally disable date mutations, simply return an empty array from the `getDates` method. For more details, check [Date Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators) on `Laravel` website.

Comment: How can I do this as part of the original query? I need to fetch quite a few rows and several different columns, so that is why I was seeking to format the date in advance.

Comment: In your model you can override that by adding `public function `getDates()` as a date mutator.
`

Answer (score 6):

I realise the original question refers to MySQL but I had the same error with MSSQL. The problem turned out to be that MSSQL's datetime column type has a precision of .001 seconds but I was setting my model's format to no precision:

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d G:i:s';
}
```

By using the newer DateTime2 column type and turning off the precision, I fixed the error. I.e.

```
datetime2(0)
```

You could instead change the format in `getDateFormat`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, I got the same error when attempting to copy a date.

```
$user->last_login = Carbon::now();

if ($user->first_login < Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1)) {
    // This is the users first login
    $user->first_login = $user->last_login; // FAILS!
}
```

Turns out Laravel casts the value of `$user->last_login` to a DateTime+Timezone string. It's no longer a Carbon object.

You could fix the error by using copies of a single Carbon object (example below), or by setting up mutators (setters) on the underlying model.

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$user->last_login = $now;

if ($user->first_login < Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1)) {
    // This is the users first login
    $user->first_login = $now;
}
```